# How can I view a CoreData to-many relationship with the sqlitebrowser tool?

Tags: ios, core-data

How can I view a CoreData to-many relationship with the sqlitebrowser tool?  I have an NSManagedObject with a to-many relationship.  I can see all of the regular fields with SQLiteBrowser when I look at the underlying SQLite Database, but I cannot see the relationships.  They must be stored to disk because they are persistent.  Where can I find them on disk??  Where is the file that stores these relationships?? How can I view that file directly using a tool like SQLiteBrowser????

Answer (score 0):

I have checked Firefox - SQLite Manager. In this there are some system table generate with name of relationship you have given, which contains relationship. 
Also you can find Z_PK key in all you table, So search into child table with z_px's value from parent table.

Hope this what you looking for.

Regards,
Punita

Comment: So, you are saying look at the primary key of the object, Z_PK, and then search where to find a reference to it??  Also, my question is very specifically, WHERE can I see "some system table generate with name of relationship"???  (The relationship being the relationship created in core data.)